# Displaying a long long int within a struct node?

Tags: c

I have the following:

```
typedef struct node{
  long long int data; 
  struct node *next; 
}node;
```

However, when I tried to store a big number like:

```
long long int finalVal =139752196320796;
node *newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); 
newNode->data = finalVal; 
newNode->next = NULL;
```

I try to print out the value of the node and get:

> -1744523748

Any tips as to why this happens?

Comment: Show the code you used to print it out, and show the value of `sizeof(long long int)` on your platform.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Bad dupe. That dupe is for a case where arithmetic produces an overflow. Literals don't overflow the same way; an integer literal too big to fit in an `int` gets a bigger type automatically.

Comment: See [C11, 6.4.4.1, paragraph 5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: You might want to take a look at the C11 link too.

Comment: @user2357112 100% spot on! you're right. but the question is not "cannot reproduce"

Comment: @CarlosRomero: can you edit to show how you're printing your value?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The problem can be reproduced both online: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ByFU6yBdG using gdb or on my machine using clang

Comment: @user2357112: Agreed — and reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are printing your value as an integer using `%d` or `%i`. Instead try using the `ll` `long long` modifier i.e. `%lld` or `lli`.

```
printf("%lld", newNode->data);
printf("%lli", newNode->data);
```

Comment: I think that an incorrect format is probably the problem, after thinking about it.  The constant should be treated as a `long long` automatically by the compiler.  What the OP sees is what you get if you use `printf("%d\n", (int)newNode->data);` (and you might get the result without the cast on a little-endian machine).  The main moral is "make sure you treat types correctly", and the secondary one is "make sure you compile with compiler warnings so such problems are spotted — and get a better compiler if it doesn't spot the problem".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so it's not a duplicate after all! I just tested, and compiler is smart enough to add  LL by itself. So printing is probably the issue. Maybe we should reopen, but it should be flagged as "unclear" or "no mcve" immediately after, or maybe there's another dupe for this.

Comment: (and your answer & my comment were wrong). You learn something everyday on SO XOR you get rep :)

Comment: note that this format doesn't work too well on windows / generates warnings unless certain options are set. But that's probably the issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the format works well on windows.  It is not an OS issue, but a compiler one.

Comment: yes, I mean: with gcc believing that Windows cannot handle the format